# why WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") should crash?

Tags: vbscript, installshield

Do you think of any reason that this line should crash:
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

... only if I launch the script from InstallShieldExpress as a custom-action.

```
MsgBox "before create ObjectShell"
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox "after create ObjectShell"
```

I never see the "after create ObjectShell" message ;-(

and if I simply launch the script by double-clicking on the script file in a windows explorer, of course everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the global `WScript` object isn't available in the InstallShield environment. You can check this using a script like this:

```
MsgBox Not IsEmpty(WScript) ' True if WScript is defined, False if it's undefined
```

If `WScript` is undefined, try using `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` instead. See also [What is the difference between CreateObject and Wscript.CreateObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/787369/113116)

Comment: Correct, InstallShield does not support WScript.