# What is the difference between creating a COM instance through CreateObject versus ActiveXObject?

Tags: wsh, activexobject, createobject

This has been touched on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787369/what-is-the-difference-between-createobject-and-wscript-createobject) in the second answer but I don't see how it answers the question (nor does the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156598.aspx) provided).

What can ActiveXObject do that CreateObject cannot, and vice-versa?

Comment: I added the wscript tag, although it could be applicable to VBA/JScript as well?

Comment: Yes - VBA can use CreateObject and JScript can use ActiveXObject, is my understanding.

Comment: Found this article on the subject over at MSDN http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/01/145686.aspx