# What is the difference between new ActiveXObject() and WScript.CreateObject()?

Tags: activex, jscript, wsh

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/using-com-objects-in-windows-script-host), one can create instances of the COM objects using both the `ActiveXObject()` and the `WScript.CreateObject()` functions. It seems like the lines

```
var objXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

and

```
var objXL = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
```

are identical. Is this a true assumption? and if not what is the difference? Examples to show the difference would be highly appreciated.

**P.S.** The post this has been flagged as a duplicate to is about the difference between VBScript's `CreateObject()` method and JScript's `WScript.CreateObject()`. It answers mention the JScript's `ActiveXObject()` constructor with no further elaborations.

Comment: Here's the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7932771/692942) from 9 years ago.

Comment: @Lankymart . thanks. hadn't seen that. but yet not answered!

Comment: Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787394/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart the question is not correct. JScript doesn't have a `CreateObject()` function like VBScript. And the answer says `I would guess there is no difference between the two functions` with no further explanations.

Comment: The answer is, there is no difference. What do you expect when you ask a question that is going to attract a lot of opinion based answers?

Comment: @Lankymart for me it is a learning opportunity to know what those two functions do. I expect to see opinions and examples and learn.

Comment: It's a Microsoft extension of the ECMAScript to support COM objects. See now obsolete [`ActiveXObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject).

Comment: In which case, do it somewhere else because [so] is not designed for opinion based questions.

Comment: @Lankymart I think the page you linked is not for classic JScript. I don't think `let` is a valid JScript command.

Comment: You're right, but ECMAScript has moved on where as JScript (ECMAScript3) didn't. In terms of a reference that is the closest you're going to get, because Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided to wipe any reference to official documentation from search engines.

Comment: @Lankymart but JScript, VBScript, WSH, and HTA are still shipped in all Windows machines out there. I honestly wonder why they never took off as JavaScript, NodJS and Electron did.

Comment: Appears as though you can still find the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.84)) but it wasn't easy.

Comment: @TylerH it is a relevant discussion but the question is completely different. At least I now know that the two are not identical, considering that the `WScript.CreateObject()`  method has a second parameter. I still need to figure out what it exactly does.

Comment: ActiveXObject dates back to JScript in IE, back when Microsoft still tried to actively promote ActiveX as a way to do scripting in web browsers.  CreateObject goes back to earlier times and has a Basic lisp.  ActiveX is more capable, also supported a visible representation of an object.  But that didn't get used much and as a programmatic widget (as used in the question) the distinction disappears.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the comment, sir. Would you be kind to elaborate on the more capable part?

Comment: Having a visible representation is a big deal.  Most programmers are familiar with the concept of a "control",  a space carved out in the host view that has its own behavior, written by programmers that don't have to talk to the host programmers every day.  But that world is not ideal, they live on an island and the boat does not arrive as often as it should.  Which is what killed it.

Answer (score 6):

### Are they the same?

The short the answer is Yes they are the same (in the sense they perform the same job of instantiating an automation object).

Basically unlike VBScript which has the global function `CreateObject()` there is no such equivalent in JScript which was based on ECMAScript 3rd Edition. So, Microsoft added its own extension `ActiveXObject` which does the same job as `CreateObject`.

Both languages can be hosted in the Windows Scripting Host which gives them access to `WScript.CreateObject()` which is another method that does exactly the same function but only in the context of the `WScript` object that is only available through the Windows Scripting Host.

### Following up

There has been some debate about whether they are the same, I still stand by my original answer they are the same. However, I will concede that I was comparing VBScript `CreateObject()` and JScript `new ActiveXObject()` not `Wscript.CreateObject()` (which is *slightly* different).

Let's be clear though, all these functions and objects serve the same purpose which is to instantiate an automation object (COM). To back this up here is the official description of each;

**WScript - [`CreateObject()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/xzysf6hc(v=vs.84))**

> *Creates a COM object*

**JScript - [`ActiveXObject` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.84))**

> *Enables and returns a reference to an Automation object*

**VBScript - [`CreateObject()` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/dcw63t7z(v=vs.84))**

> *Creates and returns a reference to an Automation object*

If they were completely the same what would the point of them be? We already have language-specific automation instantiation methods, so what would the point of `Wscript.CreateObject()` be?

The difference is when called with a second parameter it allows you to specify a prefix that will use to distinguish event handlers for that COM object.

Here is an [example taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239958/692942) that shows how the second argument is used to set a prefix of `objIE_` that will then be used to prefix any event handlers associated with that COM object, in this case, the `InternetExplorer.Application` object.

```js
// JScript
var objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","objIE_")
objIE.Visible = true

while (objIE.Visible){
    WScript.Sleep(500);
}

function objIE_NavigateComplete2(pDisp, URL){
    WScript.Echo("You just navigated to", URL)
} 

function objIE_OnQuit(){
    boolBrowserRunning = false ;
}
```

It allows an Internet Explorer instance to be opened and the URL navigated to captured through the bound event, once the Internet Explorer Window is closed the script will end.

So while not identical they do perform the same function of instantiating an Automation (COM) object.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Answer to What is the difference between CreateObject and Wscript.CreateObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787394/692942)

Comment: So `WScript.CreateObject()` is not available in the HTA files?

Comment: No, because `mshta.exe` is it’s own host. Both `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` allow the use of the `WScript` object. But other WScript objects like `WScript.Shell` can be because they are instantiated through `CreateObject()` and `new ActiveXObject()`.

Comment: Is it correct to call `ActiveXObject` an "object generator"? it is a function, not a property per se.

Comment: It’s actually more an object instance than a function as it uses the `new‘ keyword. Notice how the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.84)) calls it an "Object" not a "Function".

Comment: so it is a class? can you be kind to provide an example using the `new` keyword in another context? for example to create a String object?

Comment: There’s [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399300/692942) if it helps.

Comment: Yup. Had seen those. I am no expert here but I think we may call `ActiveXObject()` some sort of class generator. My knowledge of OOP is very primitive, but object to me is an instance of a class.

Comment: The use of `new` means it is an instance of a class, so object seems right imo. Doesn’t matter either way, think the questions been answered.

Comment: BTW the `var testString = new Number("123.22")` works. One can create `String()`, `Number()`, and `Boolean()` objects with the `new` keyword. I guess we should be able to create `function` objects as well.

Comment: Think is important to note that I originally only answered this question in an attempt to explain the differences between `CreateObject()`, `WScript.CreateObject()` and `new ActiveXObject()`.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: sadly this is not a correct answer. `new ActiveXObject()` and `WScript.CreateObject()` are not identical. for example, the latter is not available in the context of HTAs and it also has a second parameter related to events, that I haven't comprehended yet.

Comment: @Foad I'm not sure how not being available in HTAs is relevant? The `WScript` object is only available through the Windows Scripting Host, my point is they **all** perform the same function, I've tried to edit my answer to clear that up.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer it is indeed now more complete. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on the second parameter of `Wscript.CreateObject()` as also discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/jlr5k7/what_is_the_difference_between_new_activexobject/garv2mz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). It would be very kind of you to provide an example as well.