# geting special folders with shell.application

Tags: vbscript, path, special-folders

I need in a script to return the path to the current user desktop. Now I know you can do it with WScript.

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
         strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop");
```

But for my script this will not work as I cant use WScript. but I can use the shell.application object as below.

```
 dim objShell
        dim ssfWINDOWS
        dim objFolder

        ssfWINDOWS = 0
        set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
            set objFolder = objshell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, ssfWINDOWS)
                if (not objFolder is nothing) then
                Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
                    g_objIE.Document.All("logdir").Value = objFolderItem.path
                end if
            set objFolder = nothing
        set objShell = nothing
```

what is the syntax so the rather than "BrowseForFolder" i can simple return the path of the current users desktop?

IE replace the line

```
set objFolder = objshell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, ssfWINDOWS)
```

with the equilivent of.

```
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop");
```

Cheers

Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Shell.Namespace(...).Self.Path`:

```
Const ssfDESKTOPDIRECTORY = &h10
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
strDesktop = oShell.NameSpace(ssfDESKTOPDIRECTORY).Self.Path

WScript.Echo strDesktop
```

> But for my script this will not work as I cant use WScript.

Do you mean you can't use `WScript.CreateObject(...)` because `WScript` is undefined? If so, you can simply use `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")` instead. See [What is the difference between CreateObject and Wscript.CreateObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787369/what-is-the-difference-between-createobject-and-wscript-createobject).

Comment: cheers thats perfect, and you may well be right about the second point to. Cheers for the link very usefull.

Answer (score 3):

Try the namespace method:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(&H10&)
```

Where &H10& is a special folder constant for the desktop. See [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176604.aspx) for a list of all special folder constants.