# Why do I have to write WScript.Echo with WScript while it's not mandatory for CreateObject?

Tags: vbscript, echo, wsh, createobject

In VBScript, there're so many examples where users wrote `WScript.CreateObject("...")` while at the same time the script56.chm and other relevant docs advise to just write `CreateObject("...")`. And it *seems* to work the same way.

I'm wondering why is it different for `WScript.Echo` (you can't just write `Echo`...)

I read the following question and comments about the reason behind `WScript.CreateObject` but didn't seem to find anything relevant: [What is the difference between CreateObject and Wscript.CreateObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787369/what-is-the-difference-between-createobject-and-wscript-createobject)

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Pretty sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787394/692942) covers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see an incongruity because you think you are using the same thing in both cases, but you are not.

You have two different elements that collaborate to run your scripts: a script host and a script engine. The script host is the executable that initializes the scripting engine who deals with the language used. In an usual client OS install you have at least three script hosts (`wscript.exe`, `cscript.exe`, `mshta.exe`) that can use two different script engines (`VBScript` and `JScript`).

`WScript.CreateObject` is a **method** of the `WScript` object exposed by the script host (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`) to allow the scripting engine (as said `VBScript` and `JScript` are native to the OS, but you can install other engines) instantiate a COM object.

`CreateObject` (no `WScript` here) is a **function** of the `VBScript` script engine, not related to the `WScript` object or the script host.

Both share the same name, but they are not the same thing. Calling `CreateObject` function in `VBScript` is *"equivalent"* to use `new ActiveXObject( ... )` in `JScript`. In both cases you use something the scripting engine exposes, not something the script host exposes.

By example, you can use any of the two (`CreateObject` or `new ActiveXObject( ... )`) inside an `.hta` file without problems as they are part of the scripting engine, but you can not use `WScript.CreateObject` in an `.hta` file because the script host (`mshta.exe`) does not expose an `WScript` object to the scripting engine running the code.

Comment: The scripting hosts can actually use any [Active Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting) language of which VBScript and JScript are available right off the bat, other implementations *(Perl, Python etc)* have to be installed manually.

Comment: @Lankymart, Yes, that is the reason for the *"... but you can install other engines."*. Other host can also be installed (`ASP` is the most obvious), did I miss anything?

Comment: @mc-nd OK thanks, when re-reading now the 1st two answers of the question I linked to, it makes more sense to me. Both method/function act the same with only 1 parameter; the purpose/behaviour differs when adding the 2nd parameter.